# postgres having tourble to decide the best option between = and <>

Tags: postgresql

I have two approaches to update the records of a table but not confident which approach is the best.

first-way use <> operator

```
 update daily_tender_sales 
set amount = jd.amount, 
amount_count = jd.amount_count, 
amount_cancel = jd.amount_cancel, 
amount_cancel_count = jd.amount_cancel_count
from tender_sales_Json_data jd
where _drop = false AND daily_tender_sales.id = jd.id
AND(daily_tender_sales.amount <> jd.amount 
    or daily_tender_sales.amount_count <> jd.amount_count 
    or daily_tender_sales.amount_cancel <> jd.amount_cancel 
    or daily_tender_sales.amount_cancel_count <> jd.amount_cancel_count)
```

second-way use = operator

```
 update daily_tender_sales 
set amount = jd.amount, 
amount_count = jd.amount_count, 
amount_cancel = jd.amount_cancel, 
amount_cancel_count = jd.amount_cancel_count
from tender_sales_Json_data jd
where _drop = false AND daily_tender_sales.id = jd.id
AND NOT(daily_tender_sales.amount = jd.amount 
    AND daily_tender_sales.amount_count = jd.amount_count 
    AND daily_tender_sales.amount_cancel = jd.amount_cancel 
    AND daily_tender_sales.amount_cancel_count = jd.amount_cancel_count)
```

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) but I doubt there will be a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked the execution plan int helps me